# Get columns from inner queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have some question regarding below SQL:

```
SELECT mattyp.ID As mattypId, mattyp.Name As mattypName
FROM T_MaterialType as mattyp 
WHERE mattyp.ID IN                                      
      (SELECT mather_mattyp.FK_Material_Type_ID 
       FROM T_Material_T_Hersteller_T_MaterialType As mather_mattyp 
       WHERE mather_mattyp.FK_Material_Hersteller_ID IN 
             (SELECT mat_her.ID 
              FROM T_Material_T_Hersteller As mat_her
              INNER JOIN T_Material As mat ON mat_her.FK_Material_ID = mat.ID
              INNER JOIN T_Hersteller As her ON mat_her.FK_Hersteller_ID = her.ID  
              WHERE mat_her.FK_Hersteller_ID = 29 
                AND mat_her.ID IN
                    (SELECT FK_MaterialHersteller_ID 
                     FROM T_MaterialHersteller_KatSub_SubSubKat 
                     WHERE FK_KatSubKat_ID = 249 )))--AND (FK_Subsubkat_ID = 91 OR FK_Subsubkat_ID IS NULL))))
```

As you see on top I take those columns:

```
mattyp.ID As mattypId, mattyp.Name As mattypName
```

However inside whole SQL, I would like to also take:

```
Name field from table mat (T_Material) and Name field from her (T_Hersteller).
```

How can I achieve that? Currently when I do like this at the top:

```
SELECT mattyp.ID As mattypId, mattyp.Name As mattypName, mat.Name, her.Name
```

I get this error msg:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 47
>   The multi-part identifier "mat.Name" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 47
>   The multi-part identifier "her.Name" could not be bound.

I did it like this but i am not sure if this is not wrong, can anyone check?:

```
SELECT mattyp.ID As mattypId, mattyp.Name As mattypName, mat.Name, her.Name
FROM T_MaterialType as mattyp
INNER JOIN T_Material_T_Hersteller_T_MaterialType As mather_mattyp ON mattyp.ID = mather_mattyp.FK_Material_Type_ID 
INNER JOIN T_Material_T_Hersteller As mat_her ON mather_mattyp.FK_Material_Hersteller_ID = mat_her.ID
INNER JOIN T_Material As mat ON mat_her.FK_Material_ID = mat.ID
INNER JOIN T_Hersteller As her ON mat_her.FK_Hersteller_ID = her.ID  
WHERE mat_her.FK_Hersteller_ID = 29 
  AND mat_her.ID IN
      (SELECT FK_MaterialHersteller_ID 
       FROM T_MaterialHersteller_KatSub_SubSubKat  
       WHERE FK_KatSubKat_ID = 249 )--AND (FK_Subsubkat_ID = 91 OR FK_Subsubkat_ID IS NULL))))
```

Comment: Do you need to nest that many inner queries? Couldn't it be handled by normal `inner joins` ? I think that might simplify it a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, this will give the same result as your original query with IN conditions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    mattyp.ID As mattypId, 
    mattyp.Name As mattypName, 
    mat.Name, 
    her.Name
FROM T_MaterialType as mattyp 
INNER JOIN T_Material_T_Hersteller_T_MaterialType As mather_mattyp ON mather_mattyp.FK_Material_Type_ID = mattyp.ID
INNER JOIN T_Material_T_Hersteller As mat_her ON mather_mattyp.FK_Material_Hersteller_ID = mat_her.ID 
    AND mat_her.FK_Hersteller_ID = 29 
INNER JOIN T_Material As mat ON mat_her.FK_Material_ID = mat.ID
INNER JOIN T_Hersteller As her ON mat_her.FK_Hersteller_ID = her.ID  
INNER JOIN T_MaterialHersteller_KatSub_SubSubKat mat_katsub ON mat_katsub.FK_MaterialHersteller_ID = mat_her.ID
    AND mat_katsub.FK_KatSubKat_ID = 249
```

Comment: could you also look at my query is it also ok?

Comment: your query with inner join is OK, just you might need to use DISTINCT to eliminate duplicate if the data in the joined table are in one to many relation. Also you can avoid last IN condition with join as I placed in above query for performance perspective.

Comment: there could me more result so i cannot distinct